# Deleting empty spaces in a string

Tags: javascript, string, function

Okay I have a simple Javascript problem, and I hope some of you are eager to help me. I realize it's not very difficult but I've been working whole day and just can't get my head around it.

Here it goes: I have a sentence in a Textfield form and I need to reprint the content of a sentence but WITHOUT spaces.

For example: "My name is Slavisha" The result: "MynameisSlavisha"

Thank you

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to remove spaces from a textbox value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960701/javascript-to-remove-spaces-from-a-textbox-value)

Answer (score 11):

You can replace all whitespace characters:

```
var str = "My name is Slavisha" ;
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ""); // "MynameisSlavisha"
```

The `/\s+/g` regex will match any whitespace character, the `g` flag is necessary to replace all the occurrences on your string.

Also, as you can see, we need to reassign the `str` variable because Strings are *immutable* -they can't really change-.

Comment: @SlavishaZero: the way you thank people here is by picking their answer. If CMS' answer helped you the most, pick it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difference between `.replace(/\s+/g, "")` and `.replace(/\s/g, "")`. They both seem to do the same thing. If so, then which is preferred (as in faster, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
var str = 'My name is Slavisha'.split(' ').join('');
```